# How to stop infinite scroll from loading on top of page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, infinite-scroll

When the infinite scroll gets near to the end, it loads back to the top of the page and refreshes.

How do I stop that so it loads new images with previous images, and stop it from loading back at the top and refresh?

I don't want the infinite scroll to be implemented in the favourites section, only the show contents section.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

```
const resultsNav = document.getElementById('resultsNav');
const favouritesNav = document.getElementById('favouritesNav');
const imagesContainer = document.querySelector('.images-container');
const saveConfirmed = document.querySelector('.save-confirmed');
const loader = document.querySelector('.loader');


// Unsplash API
const count = 10;
const apiKey = 'UNSPLASH_API_KEY';
const apiUrl = `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=${apiKey}&count=${count}`;

let resultsArray = [];
let favourites = {};


function showContent(page) {
  window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'instant'});
  if (page === 'results') {
    resultsNav.classList.remove('hidden');
    favouritesNav.classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    resultsNav.classList.add('hidden');
    favouritesNav.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
  loader.classList.add('hidden');
}

function createDOMNodes(page) {
  const currentArray = page === 'results' ? resultsArray : Object.values(favourites);
  currentArray.forEach((result) => {
    // Card Container
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('card');
    // link
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = result.links.html;
    link.target = '_blank';

    //Images
    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = result.urls.regular;
    image.alt = 'Image';
    image.loading = 'lazy';
    image.classList.add('card-img-top');
    //Card Body
    const cardBody = document.createElement('div');
    cardBody.classList.add('card-body');
    // Save Text
    const saveText = document.createElement('p');
    saveText.classList.add('clickable');
  if (page === 'results') {
    saveText.textContent = 'Add To Favourites';
    saveText.setAttribute('onclick', `saveFavourite('${result.urls.regular}')`);
  } else {
    saveText.textContent = 'Remove Favourite';
    saveText.setAttribute('onclick', `removeFavourite('${result.urls.regular}')`);
  }

    // Append
    cardBody.append(saveText);
    link.appendChild(image);
    card.append(link, cardBody);
    imagesContainer.appendChild(card);
  });
}

function updateDOM(page) {
  // Get Favourites from localStorage
  if (localStorage.getItem('unsplashFavourites')) {
    favourites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('unsplashFavourites'));
  }
  imagesContainer.textContent = '';
  createDOMNodes(page);
  showContent(page);
}

//  Get 10 Images from Unsplash API
async function getUnplashPictures() {
// Show loader
loader.classList.remove('hidden');
  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
    resultsArray = await response.json();
    updateDOM('results');
  } catch (error) {
    // Catch Error Here
  }
}

// Add result to Favourites
function saveFavourite(itemUrl) {
  // Loop through Reuslts Array to select Favourite
  resultsArray.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.urls.regular.includes(itemUrl) && !favourites[itemUrl]) {
      favourites[itemUrl] =item;
      // Show Save Confirmation for 2 Seconds
      saveConfirmed.hidden = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        saveConfirmed.hidden = true;
      }, 2000);
      // Set Favourites in localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('unsplashFavourites', JSON.stringify(favourites));
    }
  });
}

// Remove item from Favourites
function removeFavourite(itemUrl) {
  if (favourites[itemUrl]) {
    delete favourites[itemUrl];
    // Set Favourites in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('unsplashFavourites', JSON.stringify(favourites));
    updateDOM('favourites');
  }
}

// Check to see if scrolling near bottom of page, Load More Photos
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight - 1000) {
    getUnplashPictures();
  }
});

// On Load
getUnplashPictures();
```

Comment: It's hard answer this without a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but `window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'instant'});` looks suspect. Removing it may resolve your issue with it scrolling back to the top.

Comment: @Steve Hi, I have tried removing it, but it doesn't work. Also I have include a jsfiddle. 
Appreciate any help, thanks :).

Comment: Your JSFiddle has typos and does not even demonstrate the problem though

Comment: please shorten this code/problem.

Comment: The JsFiddle doesn't even work for me, its just a white background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in two lines of your code. First, as noted in comments,

```js
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'instant'});
```

Is what scrolls the page to the top and you should remove it.
Another problem is in the fetch logic:

```js
resultsArray = await response.json();
```

Deletes the content of the whole list and replace it with the new records! That means you don't add the new data to the already-fetched records when loading more data, but replace the current data with the new.

Possible solution:

```js
const newResultsArray = await response.json();
resultsArray = resultsArray.concat(newResultsArray); // Combine new and already-fetched records
```

I changed those two lines in the jsfiddle and tried it with a mock data (the api gives errors). It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ColdAtNight. However, if I delete the imagesContainer.textContent = ''; - the add to favourites doesn't work. Is there any chance you have an alternative solutions? Thanks :).

Comment: @user8 See my edit